# In-file column deletion

Tags: awk

I am trying to delete last 4 column of multiple file. I am using gawk function. Its working for some file. But the in some output file there is nothing or less number of rows than the input file.

```
  gawk '{print >$NF".txt"} meta.txt| gawk -i inplace '{NF-=4; print}' *.txt
```

Am I doing anything wrong here??

MODIFICATION/ UPDATES: if both the command run separately without pipe gawk -i inplace work perfectly.

Comment: It may formatting of the files.  Try dos2unix on all files.

Comment: @Jotne tried dos2unix. No improvement.

Comment: Then you should try 1 and 1 file and see what is different with those file. Post an example file here that does not work.

Comment: @Jotne if I try 1 file at one time; then it work perfectly for all the files. But I was looking for something so that I dont need to fire the command one by one as some time my file number will be really high.

Comment: we can only guess without having a reproducible problem posted in your Q. Run your this on your files, `awk '{print FILENAME, NF} *.txt | sort | uniq -c`. This should show you that some files have a mix of record sizes (differnt number of columns). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter thanks. I think I figured out what the issue was. I was running another command then pipe it and run the gawk command. Now if I run it without pipe then gawk working perfect. Thank you all.

Comment: remove pipe, execute in sequence, `gawk '{print >$NF".txt"} meta.txt;  gawk -i inplace '{NF-=4; print}' *.txt`

Comment: @AkshayHegde works perfect

Comment: @user3377241 : glad to know that

Comment: Are you creating the files first and THEN removing the last 4 fields from each? Wouldn't it make sense to instead just not write those last 4 fields to each file when they're being created?

Comment: @EdMorton I am creating the files from my meta file on the basis of last column. 'gawk '{print >$NF".txt"} meta.txt.'  hence I cannot delete them in my meta.txt file

Comment: I'm not suggesting you delete them from your meta file, I'm suggesting that instead of printing all fields first and then removing 4 of them, you should simply print all-but-4 of them in the first place. I added an answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're apparently doing doesn't make sense. Instead of creating the files with all fields and then removing the last 4 fields from each file you just created, simply don't print the final 4 fields when you create the files in the first place:

```
awk '{out=$NF".txt"; NF-=4; print > out}' meta.txt
```

To not impact field separators in the remaining fields use this instead:

```
awk '{out=$NF".txt"; sub(/(\s+\S+){4}$/,""); print > out}' meta.txt
```

Both of the above assume you;re using GNU awk - the first for decrementing NF actually changing $0 and the 2nd for \s/\S shorthand.

Comment: Thanks. I  am not so good; so tried to do with limited knowledge. I am having another not so important query. my input have tab and space as delimiter. But in the output file its only space. Can I have the input delimiter in the output also?